# Importing data from Panda DataFrame to MariaDB via SQLAlchemy

Tags: pandas, database, dataframe, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to import data from 3 different DataFrames to MariaDB, in which the tables are already made. The DataFrames are made with pd.read_csv (which seems to be working properly). The engine connection seems to work. But I can't seem to get anything to write to the DB.
code:

```
from pandas.io.sql import to_sql
import sqlalchemy
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import pandas as pd
import sys

from sqlalchemy.exc import SQLAlchemyError

try:
    # reading data into memory before database population
    # stations table, without duplicates
    station_df = pd.read_csv('clean.csv', sep=';', 
    usecols=('SiteID', 'Location', 'geo_point_2d'))
    station_df = station_df.drop_duplicates()


    # readings table, without duplicates
    reading_df = pd.read_csv('clean.csv', sep=';',
    usecols=('Date Time', 'NOx', 'NO2', 'NO', 'SiteID', 'PM10', 'NVPM10',
    'VPM10', 'NVPM2.5', 'PM2.5', 'VPM2.5', 'CO', 'O3', 'SO2', 'Temperature',
    'RH', 'Air Pressure', 'DateStart', 'DateEnd', 'Current', 'Instrument Type',
    ), low_memory=False)
    reading_df = reading_df.drop_duplicates()
    reading_df.index = reading_df.index + 1

    # schema table
    schema_df = pd.read_csv('schema.csv', sep=';',
    usecols=('Measure', 'Description', 'Unit'))

    engine = create_engine("mysql://root:@localhost/pollution-db?charset=utf8")

    # populate tables
    # stations table
    station_df.to_sql(con=engine, name='stations', if_exists='append', index=False)

    # schema table
    schema_df.to_sql(con=engine, name='schema', if_exists='append', index=True)

    # readings table
    reading_df.to_sql(con=engine, name='readings', if_exists='append', index=True, index_label = 'readingid',
        dtype={'Date Time':sqlalchemy.DateTime(), 'DateStart':sqlalchemy.DateTime(), 'DateEnd':sqlalchemy.DateTime()})

    with engine.connect() as con:
        con.execute('ALTER TABLE `stations` ADD PRIMARY KEY (`SiteID`);')
        con.execute('ALTER TABLE `readings` ADD PRIMARY KEY (`readingID`);')
        con.execute('ALTER TABLE `readings` ADD PRIMARY KEY (`schemaID`);')
        con.execute('ALTER TABLE `readings` ADD FOREIGN KEY (`SiteID`) REFERENCE stations(`SiteID`);')

except SQLAlchemyError:
    sys.exit("Encountered general SQLAlchemyError. Review DB and code.")
```